# Problemas al relacionar y referenciar tablas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent, relaciones

Tengo 4 tablas, `users`, `almacenes`,`detalle_alma_users` y `detalle_articulos`; están relacionadas de esta forma:

[image: Relación de tablas]

Tengo un sistema de ventas, y quiero que según los almacenes a los que está relacionado el usuario loggeado, me aparezcan solo los artículos que estén relacionados a ese almacén. Me esta dando el error `Property [almacen_id] does not exist on this collection instance.` Y creo es por la manera en la que estoy utilizando el `->where()` pero no estoy muy segura de cómo hacerlo y no he conseguido nada en internet.

Mis relaciones están así:

`users`

```
public function almacen()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Almacen::class);
}

public function detallealmausers(){
    return $this->hasMany(DetalleAlmaUser::class);
}
```

`almacenes`

```
public function detallealmausers(){
    return $this->hasMany(DetalleAlmaUser::class);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`detalle_alma_users`

```
  public function almacen(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Almacen::class);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Y mi controlador `VentaController` es el siguiente:

```
public function create()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $clientes = Cliente::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $detallearticulos = DetalleArticulo::where('almacen_id','=',$user->detallealmausers->almacen_id)->get();
    $articulos = Articulo::where('estado', 'ACTIVO')->get();
    $venta = Venta::get();
    return view('admin.venta.create', compact('clientes', 'detallearticulos', 'articulos', 'venta'));
}
```

Comment: por lo que veo `users` y `almacenes` tienen una relacion de many to many, es correcto?.

Comment: Sí, ¿no debería ser así?

Comment: Solo pregunto, es bueno que incluyas los detalles de tus preguntas, si bien puede verse en el diagrama, si lo detallas en el texto seria mejor ya que a veces algunas personas no pueden ver las imagenes. Por lo que entiendo quieres saber realizar una consulta a tablas con relaciones m to m, es correcto?

Comment: Sí, porque users puede tener más de un almacén, al igual que los detalles de los artículos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terminé consiguiendo lo que necesitaba en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231862/laravel-eloquent-has-with-wherehas-what-do-they-mean), la función de `whereHas()`, para poder adicionarle un filtro de búsqueda al modelo.

```
public function create()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        
            foreach ($user->detallealmausers as $detalle) {    
                $detalles[] = array('almacen_id' => $detalle->almacen_id);               
            }

            $articulos = Articulo::where('estado', 'ACTIVO')
                       ->where('stock', '>', 0)
                       ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) use ($detalles){
                                  $user = Auth::user();

                                  $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $detalles);
            
                       })->with('detallearticulos')->get();               
               

        $clientes = Cliente::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        $venta = Venta::get();
        return view('admin.venta.create', compact('clientes', 'articulos', 'venta', 'user'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel en su documentacion muestra que para las relaciones Many to Many lo modelos deben ir de la siguiente forma:

```
//Esto en tu MODELO users
public function almacenes()
{
    //Esto para las relaciones many to many, te dejo tres opciones con su explicacion
    //Primera opcion
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Almacen');
    //Segunda opcion,a mi me parece mejor para evitar errores
    //O de esta otra forma especificando la tabla intermedia y las claves foraneas
    
    //El primer parametro es el modelo relacionado, segundo parametro la tabla intermedia
    //Tercer y cuarto parametro las foraneas que relacionan a user y almacenes
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Almacen','detalle_alma_users','almacen_id','user_id');
    //Tercer opcion Para obtener la informacion de la tabla intermedia (detalle_alma_users) debes usar pivot
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Almacen','detalle_alma_users','almacen_id','user_id')->withPivot('created_at');
}
```

En el modelo de almacenes :

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    //O cualquiera de las opciones que te comente arriba
}
```

Para consultar y traer la informacion de la tablas tablas relacionadas lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma:
Por ejemplo en el controlador de tu usuario:

```
//En el userController
public function index()
{
    //Listamos todos los usuarios
    //Aca podrias filtrar con un where
    $users = User::select()
        ->get();
    //Aca usas la relaciones de tu modelo para incluir los almacenes para cada registro obtenido
    foreach($users as $user){
        $user->almacenes;
    }
    //finalmente retornas tu coleccion de usuarios la cual va a tener los almacenes que tienen relacionados
    return response()->json([ 
        "Usuarios" => $users
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

De esta forma me sirvio a mi para consultar tablas con relacion many to many, espero te sirva.
Aca te dejo la documentacion de laravel (ingles) para que tengas una idea de como hacerlo
Fuente: [Documentacion laravel many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

El error que te aparece a ti (`Property [almacen_id] does not exist on this collection instance.`), supongo que es por lo que te comente arriba, a veces es mejor especificar las claves foraneas y la tabla intermedia porque a veces laravel asume los nombres de las foraneas como `mytabla_id` y las tablas intermedias como `almacenes_user` y tu migracion puede que la cree como: `almacen_user`

Comment: Es que la relación me funciona, el problema no es eso; es que a la hora de yo querer traerme solo los detalles de los artículos y los artículos que estén asociados a los mismos almacenes que el usuario loggeado; por ejemplo, si el usuario está asociado al almacén 1 y 3, que me traiga solo los artículos que estén asociados al almacén 1 y 3; probablemente el título de la pregunta está mal, porque no es la relación sino a la hora del ``where()``, al realizar la consulta